# What is the quantity of the "a" in "maxime"?

Tags: vowel-quantity, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

When I come across the word *maxime* in macronized texts, it usually lacks a macron over the first vowel. In Ørberg's *Lingua Latīna* series, however, in which the macrons are (from what I understand) very reliable, it's always macronized *māximē*. At first I thought that perhaps the macron was there to mark a vowel made long by position before the letter "x," but in other words with "x" (*exercitus, mox, vexāvit*, and so on) there's no macron.

So what's the deal? Is the vowel long by nature or not?

Comment: It should be short in maximus and maxime but then there's some evidence that it could be long. See e.g. footnote 32 on p. 175 in Weiss *Outline.*

Comment: Good to see you around.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Good to be around! And thanks for emailing a while ago—I'm sorry for not responding (it's still in my inbox, so at SOME point I will!), but I appreciated it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the one hand, we have MAX(IMO), A with an apex in CIL VI 2080 17

However, as [De Angelis and Chilà 2015](https://doi.org/10.1515/flih-2015-0004) put it,

> "the interpretation of the vowel of *maximus* as long is anything but certain" (p. 92).

Allen thinks the long a is doubtful there (Allen 1978: 70). Forston argues the apex there could be a mark of the "final member of the phrase" (Weiss 209: 175) or it could be a scribal error. Kortland finds this evidence "too weak for any conclusions."

**"The long a camp":** Leumann 1977 gives māx- and mentions it in §120 (Lachmann's Law); so does Tronskii 1960 (p. 99). Jasanoff 2004 also puts it together with two other non-participles under same Lachmann's Law (p. 414).

Also see http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dmaximus1

Weiss takes a cautious position on this - he mentions it in the section devoted to Lachmann's Law, with a caveat.

Comment: A very thorough answer.

Comment: Plus much better sources.

Answer (score 6):

I've never seen a macron'd *ā* in *maximus* before. But the evidence is sparse on this matter; since the first syllable is always long by position, poetic meter doesn't tell us anything about the vowel quantity.

*Maximus* comes from the root of *magis*, which is known to have a short *a*, and *mājor*, which had a heavy first syllable but was probably a short *a* and long *jj* (see the note in [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14/when-is-an-i-not-an-i/91#91)). So etymologically it seems to be short. But vowel quantities can change when the sounds around them change, so this isn't foolproof evidence.