# Classical words for spelt

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, example-request, biology

The [Latin Wikipedia article about spelt](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelta) mentions two ancient Latin names for spelt: *spelta* and *scandala*.
I have found *spelta* used in more recent Latin, but nothing ancient.
I have never seen *scandala* — apart from being the plural of *scandalum*.
I presume there is nothing scandalous about spelt, so these words should be unrelated.
My dictionaries recognize neither *spelta* nor *scandala*.

Which words were used for spelt in antiquity?
In other words, is Vicipaedia correct?
If you can give a word, please indicate if it was reconstructed or actually attested.
For attested words I would like to see use examples.

Spelt is old enough to have an ancient name, but this is no proof that such a name must exist.
It may be that it was not given a separate name if it was considered merely a type of wheat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find Vicipædia fairly untrustworthy as a rule. *Scandala* does not occur in Lewis & Short; perhaps the author(s) of the Vicipædia article are thinking of *secāle*, which is used in Pliny of black spelt (though I don't know what the difference is between spelt and black spelt, and some apparently think *secāle* refers to rye).

*Spelta* is part of the Linnaean name for spelt, *Triticum spelta*. According to Lewis & Short, *spelta* is used in Rhemnius Fanninus and Hieronymus, two fifth-century-A.D. authors, to mean "spelt."

However, Lewis & Short also offer several other options:

> **ador, oris and ōris, n.** cf. 1. edo, ἔδομαι, Engl. to eat, Goth. ita, Sanscr. admi; and Ang.-Sax. ata = Engl. oat, and Sanscr. annam (for adnam) = food, corn, a kind of grain, spelt, Triticum spelta, Linn. (acc. to Paul. ex Fest.: *Ador farris genus, edor quondam appellatum ab edendo, vel quod aduratur, ut fiat tostum, unde in sacrificio mola salsa officitur*, p. 3 Mull.: *Ador frumenti genus, quod epulis et immolationibus sacris pium putatur, unde et adorare, propitiare religiones, potest dictum videri*, Non. 52, 20): *cum pater ipse domus palea porrectus in horna Esset ador loliumque*, Hor. S. 2, 6, 89: *adoris de polline*, Aus. Mon. de Cibis, p. 238; Gannius ap. Prisc. p. 700: *satos adoris stravisse*, id. ib.: *ardor adōris*, id. ib. (Ador is often indeclinable, acc. to Prisc. p. 785, 100 P.)

and

> **far farris, n.** 1 FER-, a sort of grain, spelt (roasted and ground), L.
>
> —Corn, grain: *flava farra*, V.
>
> —Coarse meal, grits: *olus ac far*, H.: *Mollivit Penates Farre pio*, sacrificial meal, H., V., Tb.: *torrida cum micā farra*, O.
>
> —Bread: *non sine farre*, H.: *una Farris libra*, H.: *caninum*, coarse bread for dogs, Iu.

being the most well supported. (*Alica*, *mola*, *sēmen*, and *zēa* also have "spelt" as possible definitions in L&S, but they seem to have come to refer to spelt, if in fact they do, more by metonymy than by actual definition. Not that that makes it any less a word for spelt, but the citations don't seem particularly convincing or numerous.)

Comment: Regarding "farris," in modern Italian, "farro grande" is spelt.

Comment: Hunh—I thought it was just *farro*. Shows you what I know! (Though of course *farina* is "flour*, so I wonder whether etymologically at some point they were just like, oh, let's just call all grains "far-something" and be done with it.

Comment: It usually is just called farro in the U.S., but "farro" can be any one of three related grains: einkorn, emmer, or spelt, which are, respectively, known as farro piccolo, medio, and grande, in Italian (though I don't know if Italians typically make the distinction either).

Comment: I think *far* is the best: '*farris seges*' occurs in Livy, so it's not just 'corn'

Comment: Actually, bizarrely, in the version I'm looking at, Lewis Elementary has *fār*, but Lewis & Short has *far*. (I go back and forth between both, hence my mixed transcription.) I've removed it so that at least the answer is using one dictionary instead of two, but more than that I don't know.

Comment: Ah. I use latinlexicon.org, where they don't seem to mark short vowels.

Comment: That would make sense, given the double r in the other cases.