# Are there specific exceptions to the rule of lengthening a vowel before "ns" or "nf"?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation, vowel-quantity

A while ago, I wrote an [answer summarizing my understanding of the rule that a vowel is long in Classical Latin before *ns* or *nf*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/5174/9).

As far as I know, this rule applied very regularly. But I'm not sure whether there are any specific words known to have been an exception to this rule.

By "specific words", I mean that I'm thinking of a word where it would have been generally agreed by educated speakers of Classical Latin that a short vowel was correct: not just a word where we have evidence that the regular long-vowel pronunciation was usual at some point, but a short-vowel pronunciation also existed because of the support of analogy. (E.g. in words prefixed with *in-,* we have evidence from Romance of pronunciations with *ǐn-* before S or F, as in French *enfant* from Latin *infans,* but the classical pronunciation of the Latin word is still thought to have a long vowel in the first syllable. I'm not looking for examples like that.)

## Contexts where I'm less sure that the rule applied

#### Loan words

One situation where I'm a bit uncertain is loans from Greek. I haven't found any Greek word containing a short vowel followed by *ns* that became a firmly established Latin word during the classical period, but I did find the word *[metensomatosis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmetensomatosis)* (from μετενσωμάτωσις) which apparently was used in Ecclesiastical Latin, and I wondered whether we can say anything about whether a Classical Latin speaker would have used a short vowel before the *ns* in this word.

#### Perfect and past participle forms with "ns"

Another situation where I'm not entirely sure is perfect forms and past participles containing *ns.* My understanding is that there are fewer sources that mention vowel length before *ns* in this context compared to other contexts. Allen's *Vox Latina* cites a passage from Cicero that talks about lengthening in prefixed words that start with *ins, inf, cons, conf*, and a passage from Probus that talks about words ending in *-ns,* but mentions only "sporadic references to the length of the vowel before *ns* and *nf* in other contexts" ([p. 66](https://books.google.com/books?id=aexkj_0oj3MC&pg=PA66)).

I have always thought that participles like *mansus* and perfects like *mansi* must have contained long vowels before the *ns* in accordance with the lengthening rule, but it seems like some sources suggest a short vowel might be possible in this kind of context. For example, Bennett mentions a source that indicates a short vowel, although he treats it as unreliable: "Priscian lends the weight of his authority to such forms as *trăxī, mănsī, dŭxī,* which certainly had a long vowel in the best period" ([p. 62](https://books.google.com/books?id=Nj56evL5Vg0C&pg=PA62)).

I believe that most linguists share Bennett's disregard for Priscian's description of a short vowel in this context, but I'm not entirely sure.

#### Between words

This last question is a little different, but it's related enough that I think it makes sense to include it in this post. I think that the rule of vowel lengthening before *ns* or *nf* never applied across word boundaries to lengthen a vowel in the last syllable of a word ending in N, but I'm not completely sure. My understanding is that words like *pecten, crimen* and *in* are thought to have ended in a consonant [n] (unlike words ending in *-m*, which are thought to have ended in nasalized vowels except for when they were followed by a closely connected word starting with a plosive or nasal) and that while this [n] might have become assimilated across word boundaries to the place of a following consonant, it isn't thought to have been lost or vocalized before a word starting with S or F.