# cōnsīde! or consīde!?

Tags: spelling

the first page of the textbook I have gives the imperative "cōnsīde" for "sit down". But the 555 verbs book  lists the verb in the I form as consīdō and says it is declined the same as resīdō, which is verb 433 in the book, where the imperative is resīde, so the corresponding form must be consīde. where there isnt a macron on the o.

Is either book or both wrong or are there 2 versions of the same verb, or maybe different verbs in different eras?

Comment: [Related 1](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5170/is-there-any-rule-to-the-length-of-e-in-ensis/5174#5174); [related 2](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/10903/are-there-specific-exceptions-to-the-rule-of-lengthening-a-vowel-before-ns-or).

Comment: If [this](https://www.amazon.com/Big-Gold-Book-Latin-Verbs/dp/0071417575) is the book you are talking about, it says on page 1 that "the quantitiy of most vowels followed by two or more consonants cannot be decided from Latin verse and are [sic] not marked". I hope you didn't pay $190 for that thing; although with this habit it is in good company.

Comment: ok, o before ns is always long. Practising long vowels I have wondered to what extent a long vowel is in fact time spent forming an adjacent consonant? eg with say sedēbit, I find myself spending more time on the d and b, than say the d with sedet. And with the 4 verbs where I have written out the 4 main tenses, the b is always preceded by a long e. another eg sēdī, I spend extra time on the s and d, like ssseeeddddeeee. versus sedet where minimal time on the s and d. But maybe I am not saying the sounds right! It would seem tricky to say the consonant short and the vowel long.

Comment: Roughly speaking, there should be no change in the consonants, and the long vowel sound should be held for twice as long as the short ones.  I think all English speakers naturally do this in some environments, depending on dialect.  I as a speaker of American English with a fairly "standard" accent, pronounce "bat" with a short vowel and "bath" and "bad" with a long vowel of the same quality ([æ]).  If you can mimic this accent and you drop the final consonants, but retain the vowel sounds, you will hear the difference between a short and a long [æ].