# Why is the prefix con- sometimes short, sometimes long?

Tags: vowel-quantity, prefix, phonetics

A friend sent me this image:

[image: Cat lying in Colosseum bed, pun on Caesar’ Laconism]

Her question was simple: Is the Latin any good? The Latin indeed is good, and if one accepts the English to be in LOLcat, the English checks out as well.

However …

I also added a comment, that it would be even better were the long vowels marked (‘though many consider that to not be a necessity’), which is when I discovered that the expected *vēnī, vīdī, ***cōn**vēnī, cōnsēdī* did not match what the dictionary said: **vēnī, vīdī, *con*vēnī, cōnsēdī**; in fact, I assumed there was (yet another) error in the Wiktionary entry before I checked my dictionary, and indeed there are numerous words starting with the prefix *cō̆n-*, some of which should be long, some short. Why is this? What causes *cōnsīdō* to to have a long vowel whereas *conveniō* has a short one?

My immediate guess is that the vowel is lengthened due to the following present tense long vowel and that this is retained throughout the paradigm, but this is mere guesswork. In other words, I believe that this is not something to do with obscure Old Latin or Proto-Italic, but rather that this is an example of phonetic rules (that I do not fully understand) being at work. I would really appreciate an answer that can explain why this quantity change is at work and which rules (if any) govern this change.

Comment: Conveni for “I fit” is probably stretching things for parallelism, but some construction with convenire probably works.

Comment: Agreed. I would say it counts, agreeing with you.

Comment: @Kingshorsey It works in Russian for what it's worth, but the meaning isn't exactly "to occupy the space snugly" centered on the object, but "to be deemed fit" centered on the person who passes the judgement, as in "to suit". I think it's the same in Latin; I can only think of *quadrāre.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can consider the underlying length of the vowel in *con-* to be short: this is the default.

In *cōnsēdī*, and in the majority of cases where the vowel in the prefix *cō̆(n)-* is long, it is a result of the [regular lengthening of any vowel before *ns* or *nf*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5170/is-there-any-rule-to-the-length-of-e-in-ensis?noredirect=1&lq=1). The same lengthening causes *in-s..., in-f...* to be realized as **īns-, īnf-.**

Aside from that, I only know of one other, much less common context where the prefix *cō-* shows up with a long vowel: some words where the unprefixed form starts with the letter *n*, such as *cōnectō, cōnītor.* Some words with *n* instead take the form *cog-,* as in *cognōscō, cognātus.* Forms with *con-n-* are apparently a more recent alternative to *cō-n.*

Comment: I take it then that _v_ is governed by the same rule as _f_ and that /z/ would cause the same lengthening, were it a phoneme in Latin?

Comment: @CannedMan: Lengthening of the vowel is not attested as far as I know before *v*: its original pronunciation was as a semivowel [w], and that is thought to have still been the general value during the "Classical Latin" period (1st century BC) and possibly persisted up through the 5th century AD (see [previous question on dating of the change from w](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/325)).

Comment: @CannedMan V /w/ is a liquid and patterns with /j, l, r/, not with fricatives, so there was probably optional assimilation into /ww/ but no lengthening. /z/ is a Greek "phonostyleme", but  this is either always double or an affricate, so /zz/ or /dz/. After /n/ it was almost certainly the latter (/ndz/) and didn't lengthen the vowel.

Comment: @Asteroides: Yes, of course! (I speak with a Classical pronunciation myself, so I am not sure what I was thinking.) How about after the sound change? Did /v/ (not /w/) cause lengthening the same way /f/ did?